# Computing an average based on lists in another function

Tags: python, function

So I need to generate a mean for both the list of x coordinates and the list of y coordinates from one function using another function, but I'm not exactly sure how to do so. Here's what I've got so far, the first function is correct, it's just the second one that needs work, I'm just not sure what to do. 'datafile1' is simply a list of x and y coordinates separated by a tab. I should mention that this has to be done through a separate function, otherwise I would have just done this in a more simpler way.

```
import math
import statistics

def fileRead():
    "Reads the input file and stores the x and y coordinates in a parallel list"

    dataFile = open('datafile1.txt', 'r')
    dataList = []                                   # list comprised of x and y pairs
    x = []                                          # list comprised of just x coordinates
    y = []                                          # list comprised of just y coordinates

    for dataLine in dataFile:
        dataList.append(dataLine)
        dataSplit = dataLine.split()
        x.append(float(dataSplit[0]))
        y.append(float(dataSplit[1]))

    return x, y


def getMean(dataList):
    "Computes the mean of the data set"

    dataMean = statistics.mean(dataList)

    return dataMean
```

Answer (score 0):

Since calculating the mean isn't exactly complex (it's just a function call), why don't you just calculate it inline right after calling `fileRead()`?

```
(x, y) = fileRead()
xMean = statistics.mean(x)
yMean = statistics.mean(y)
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that it has to be done through separate functions (as per request of the problem). Otherwise I would have done this. Will add this to the OP.

Comment: Then pass both `x` and `y` into the `getMean` function then calculate their means separately within the function? I mean, instead of passing the aggregated xy pairs.

Comment: I think the way i'm supposed to do it is by only passing one parameter (a single list, either a list of X's or Y's) through the function and then call the function e.g. getMean(x) in order to get xAvg. I just don't know how to allow reference to the lists from my first function outside of the function itself.

Comment: You're misinterpreting what i'm trying to say. I can't do that because i'm unsure of how to reference the variables outside of the first function. That is the problem i'm having.

Comment: It's a function for a reason. It was made to encapsulate implementation without leaking its variables outside its scope. Call both `fileRead` and `getMean` outside all functions.